# Subscripting subdata obtained from range in Swift 4 results in EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift

In Xcode 9.4, I have the following code in a Swift playground:

```
import Foundation

let data = Data([UInt8](arrayLiteral: 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ))
print (data[0])

let subdata = data.subdata(in: 2..<data.count)
print (subdata[0])

let subdataUsingIndex = data[2..<data.count]
print (subdataUsingIndex[0])
```

When this code runs, it crashes on the final line, where I try to subscript `subadataUsingIndex`.

[image: Image of the crash]

It is also happening in a non-playground project. Have I run into a language bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `subdataUsingIndex` is actually a `Slice<Data>` whose `startIndex` is `2`, not `0`.

Comment: @rmaddy is the Swift documentation wrong, then? The following says that `subscript` just returns a `Data`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779919-subscript

Comment: Wrong subscript. You are using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2949132-subscript

Comment: Wow, that is confusing. I guess I still don't understand `typealias` 
 - `Data.Index` is a typealias of `Int`, and I didn't even see that `subscript` definition, so I figured I was using the one I linked. That clears things up.

Comment: @rmaddy - wait a second, I think I'm still not getting something. I changed that last statement to `print(type(of: subdataUsingIndex))` and I get back `Data` in the console.

Comment: I saw the same thing. I think that's just how `Slice<Data>` prints its type. Confusing, yes.

Comment: @rmaddy The subscript you link to [is a default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/58933d88c57fdca8d84ac7c0b8cace3aa349d4a8/stdlib/public/core/MutableCollection.swift#L199) offered by `MutableCollection` (which I'm pretty sure should be constrained to `where SubSequence == Slice<Self>` [like the non-mutable variant](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/58933d88c57fdca8d84ac7c0b8cace3aa349d4a8/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1132), and thus shouldn't be applicable to `Data`).

Comment: `Data` in fact is its own slice type, so [its implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/58933d88c57fdca8d84ac7c0b8cace3aa349d4a8/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Data.swift#L1681) returns `Data`, and that's the implementation that will be used by default when subscripting a `Data` value with a range (such as in OP's example).

Comment: (oops a couple of those links got messed up, here's a fixed one for the non-mutable default implementation of the `Slice` subscript that's correctly constrained: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7a4e0a32f6c13d55ab79f13393c15446384999b4/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1132)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data.subdata**
 Returns a new copy of the data in a specified range.

But the other one is data slice because data confirm to `Collection Protocol` we can slice it on ranges Like array using subscribe syntax

```
let subdataUsingIndex = data[2..<data.count]
```

`lower-bound` 2  and `upper-bound` is 4

```
 let data = Data([UInt8](arrayLiteral: 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ))
            print (data[0])

            let subdata = data.subdata(in: 2..<data.count)
            print (subdata[0])

            let subdataUsingIndex = data[2..<data.count]
            print (subdataUsingIndex[2])
```

See image
[image]

Comment: You should provide the solution, explicitly. In this case, I guess you could just use `2...`

Comment: I think image syntax explains its self

Comment: @Alexander Even better, `startIndex`. No need to hardcode any number.

Comment: Ok Minutes and will do